# html5 save edited content as image or pdf

Tags: html, web-applications, jquery-mobile, save, webpage-screenshot

(I'm new to this)
I want to create a html5 page/application with text boxes to be filled out.

My objective is that once the user has completed filling out the empty fields they can hit one button on the webpage to save the content (including all pictures, texts, and the fields they completed) all as either an image or even pdf for printing later.

Also note I'm doing this for mobile platforms, so I want the user to be able to store on their device after editing from their device. So options such html to pdf converter sites aren't usable.

Anyway this possible? Thanks.